# Update fragment from server when app starts in Android

Tags: java, android, json, android-fragments, android-volley

I am making a mail app. My main activity is the activity that is called when the app starts - it is set to be the launcher activity in manifest:

```
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

In my main activity I have three fragments - inbox, sent mail and my profile. I can send and receive mails from server.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

private SessionManager session;
private SQLiteHandler db;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    // SqLite database handler
    db = new SQLiteHandler(getApplicationContext());
    // session manager
    session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());

    if (!session.isLoggedIn()) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    } else {

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.sliding_tabs);
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText(getString(R.string.tab_one)));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText(getString(R.string.tab_two)));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText(getString(R.string.tab_three)));
        tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);
        tabLayout.setTabMode(TabLayout.MODE_FIXED);

        final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        final PagerAdapter adapter = new PagerAdapter
                (getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
        tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });

        ...
```

In my inbox fragment I use [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/07/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-volley/) example to get emails from server. But there is a problem - when I start my app, the sent mail fragment does not update, it only updates when I log in a user. **How to update the fragment every time I start the app**?

My sent mail:

```
public class SentmailsFragment extends Fragment {

private static final String TAG = SentmailsFragment.class.getSimpleName();

private ProgressDialog pDialog;
private List<Sentmail> sentmailList = new ArrayList<>();
private ListView listView;
private CustomListAdapter adapter;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                         ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sentmails, container, false);

    listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.sentmails_list);
    adapter = new CustomListAdapter(getActivity(), sentmailList);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());

    pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
    pDialog.show();

    SQLiteHandler db = new SQLiteHandler(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    HashMap<String, String> user = db.getUserDetails();
    final String userId = user.get("uid");

    StringRequest sentmailReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
            AppConfig.URL_GET_SENT_MAIL, new Response.Listener<String>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.d(TAG, "SentMail Response: " + response.toString());
            try {
                JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                boolean error = jObj.getBoolean("error");

                if (!error) {
                    JSONArray sentmails = jObj.getJSONArray("sentmail");

                    Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                    hidePDialog();

                    // Parsing json
                    for (int i = 0; i < sentmails.length(); i++) {
                        try {

                            JSONObject obj = sentmails.getJSONObject(i);
                            Sentmail sentmail = new Sentmail();
                            sentmail.setUserName(obj.getString("name"));
                            if (obj.getString("image") != null && !obj.getString("image").isEmpty()) {
                                sentmail.setThumbnailUrl(obj.getString("image"));
                            }
                            sentmail.setTitle(obj.getString("title"));
                            sentmail.setMessage(obj.getString("message"));
                            sentmail.setDate(obj.getString("event_date"));
                            sentmail.setTime(obj.getString("event_time"));

                            // adding sentmail to sentmail array
                            sentmailList.add(sentmail);

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }

                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                } else {
                    // Error. Get the error message
                    String errorMsg = jObj.getString("error_msg");
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // JSON error
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Sentmail Error: " + error.getMessage());
        }
    }) {

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() { 
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("user_id", userId);

            return params;
        }

    };

    // Adding request to request queue
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(sentmailReq, "req_return_sentmail");

    return view;
}
```

Comment: where is inbox fragment code?

Comment: @Vivek Mishra I can post the inbox fragment code, but I posted (this)[http://www.androidhive.info/2014/07/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-volley/] because I used this example. I didn't want to put too much code.

Comment: you have added all the code except related one then

Comment: and your link is broken too

Comment: are you calling the api to get the updated list of mails in your inbox fragment?

Comment: @vivek-mishra I updated my code with my sent mail fragment

Comment: @Anjali I added my fragment code

Comment: Are you storing your User details on successful  login? There might be the case you may not be getting the uid when user is already logged in. check your database operation that you are not mistakenly deleting the user details.

Comment: @Anjali I get the correct info for the user and email, so I should get the uid as well.  `@Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String CREATE_LOGIN_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_USER + "("
                + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_NAME + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_EMAIL + " TEXT UNIQUE," + KEY_UID + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_CREATED_AT + " TEXT" + ")";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_LOGIN_TABLE);`

Comment: Share your getUserDetails method code

Comment: @Anjali  `SQLiteHandler db = new SQLiteHandler(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        HashMap<String, String> user = db.getUserDetails();
        final String userId = user.get("uid");`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123216/discussion-between-anjali-and-kemo).

Comment: What is written inside getUserDetails method

Comment: @Anjali `public HashMap<String, String> getUserDetails() {
HashMap<String, String> user = new HashMap<String, String>();
String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_USER;

SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
// Move to first row
cursor.moveToFirst();
if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
user.put("name", cursor.getString(1));
user.put("email", cursor.getString(2));
user.put("uid", cursor.getString(3));
user.put("created_at", cursor.getString(4));
}
cursor.close();`

Comment: have you debug your code? are you getting uid in your getUserDetails() method?

Comment: @Anjali Yes, I get all the user details including the uid.

Comment: try to call sentmailReq in onResume of your fragments

Comment: @Anjali Is there a way to do that in my MainActivity? Instead of updating a fragments when I open them can I update them automatically when I start the app?

Comment: in which tab is your sent mail fragment resides?

Comment: @Anjali it is in tab_two

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your main activity code like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

private SessionManager session;
private SQLiteHandler db;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    // SqLite database handler
    db = new SQLiteHandler(getApplicationContext());
    // session manager
    session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());

    if (!session.isLoggedIn()) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    } else {

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.sliding_tabs);
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText(getString(R.string.tab_one)));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText(getString(R.string.tab_two)));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText(getString(R.string.tab_three)));
        tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);
        tabLayout.setTabMode(TabLayout.MODE_FIXED);

        final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        final PagerAdapter adapter = new PagerAdapter
                (getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
        tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
if (tab.getPosition() == 1) {

// call your sent email request and stored that in db after that in your fragment fetch the content from db and display it on ui
}
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: Is there a way to display it without adding it to the db? I want to update it directly from the server.

Comment: you can send the list directly to your fragment using intent. but before doing that you have yo implement your List object to either serializable or parcelable

Comment: I will try to do this. It should work with this code from above, right? Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

Move the part of your logic that needs to be updated every time user start the app to onResume() callback of the fragment.

Comment: Should I add it to MainActivity to update all the fragments?